# Set Pixel from Bitmap and display it

Tags: android

I want to make a simple test programm which set the color of the pixel onPress.

My Code:

```
public class DrawActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView iv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        int height = display.getHeight();

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);

        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        iv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                bitmap.setPixel((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY(), Color.BLUE);
                Log.e("DRAW", String.valueOf(event.getX())+" "+String.valueOf(event.getY()));

                Log.e("DRAW",String.valueOf(Color.BLUE)+" "+ bitmap.getPixel((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()));
                iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Log:

> 03-31 22:56:12.072: E/DRAW(6148): 297.65625 194.0 03-31 22:56:12.091:
>   E/DRAW(6148): -16776961 -16776961 03-31 22:56:13.341: E/DRAW(6148):
>   355.3125 315.875 03-31 22:56:13.341: E/DRAW(6148): -16776961 -16776961 03-31 22:56:13.865: E/DRAW(6148): 243.28125 481.5 03-31 22:56:13.865:
>   E/DRAW(6148): -16776961 -16776961 03-31 22:56:14.248: E/DRAW(6148):
>   93.28125 511.1875 03-31 22:56:14.248: E/DRAW(6148): -16776961 -16776961 03-31 22:56:14.537: E/DRAW(6148): 35.625 472.125 03-31 22:56:14.537: E/DRAW(6148): -16776961 -16776961

The problem is that the pixel is never blue on touch.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you dry setting more than 1 pixel? maybe the pixel is too small and you just don't see it. also i had a bug once in a listview when i set the divider height to 1px it didn't show up, when set to 2px the divider appeared.